# Issue calling firebase function

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am developing an Android app and I also have some cloud functions already created in my Firebase. My problem is that when I try to call a function, I just get no answer, like nothing happens.

**My function:**

```
    private Task<String> createUser(HashMap<String, Object> data) {
    // Create the arguments to the callable function, which is just one string
    return mFunctions
            .getHttpsCallable("createUser")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                @Override
                public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                    // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                    // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
                    // propagated down.
                    String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                    return result;
                }
```

**Where I call it:**

```
                       mCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (!mName.getText().toString().isEmpty() &&
                                    !mAge.getText().toString().isEmpty() &&
                                    !mBio.getText().toString().isEmpty() &&
                                    !mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty()){
                                data.put("email", userEmail);
                                data.put("age", mAge.getText());
                                if (mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Hombre")
                                    data.put("sex", "M");
                                else
                                    data.put("sex", "F");
                                data.put("name", mName.getText());
                                createUser(data);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Usuario Creado!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Completar todos los campos",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

I really don't know whats wrong with it, and I don't know a way of finding the error.

If anyone can help me I would be really grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding [addOnFailureListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnFailureListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener)) and logging the exception and [addOnCancelListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnCanceledListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCanceledListener)) to see if perhaps the request is canceled.

Comment: I added an OnCompleteListener and I discovered that the problem was that I forgot to put .toString() after the .getText() from the text boxes in the data that I added into the HashMap. Solved!